# Read Modbus register and log to csv

Tags: python, sockets, csv, logging, modbus

I am newbie to python. I have an application where I would like to read a Modbus input register and log the data to a csv file every 10 seconds, I guess the time period is irrelevant. I can read a register, I can log to a csv, I can log to a csv every 10 seconds, but I am struggling to do all of this in the right order.

How would I rearrange my code below to open the port and log the latest register value? At the moment the code opens the port once, reads the value and then keeps logging the same value every 10 seconds.

```
# Code
import socket
import struct
import time
import csv

# Create a TCP/IP socket
TCP_IP = '169.254.84.141'
TCP_PORT = 502
BUFFER_SIZE = 0
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

try:
# Ask user for Modbus options
unitId = 5
functionCode = 4
startRegister = 00
numRegister = 16

# Construct request packet
req = struct.pack('>3H 2B 2H', 0, 0, 6, int(unitId), int(functionCode), int(startRegister), int(numRegister))
sock.send(req)

# Calculate receipt packet buffer and structure
BUFFER_SIZE = (3*2) + (3*1) + (int(numRegister)*2)
rec = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

def setB():
    global BH
    BH = 'B' #1
def setH():
    global BH
    BH = 'H' #2

functionLookup = {
    1 : setB, # Read Coils (1 byte)
    2 : setB, # Read Input Discrete Registers (1 byte)
    3 : setH, # Read Holding Registers (2 byte)
    4 : setH  # Read Input Registers (2 byte)
}
functionLookup[int(functionCode)]()

s = struct.Struct('>3H 3B %s%s' %(numRegister, BH))
data = s.unpack(rec)


# Wait a couple of seconds before disconnecting
time.sleep(2);
Tank1Vol = data[6]
Tank1 = "Tank 1 Volume"
Units = "Litres"
Tank1csv = Tank1, (Tank1Vol),(Units)
starttime=time.time()
while True:

  print ("tick")
  print (Tank1csv)

  time.sleep(10.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 10.0))

  with open("Tank Level.csv", "a") as TanksFile:
      TanksFileWriter = csv.writer(TanksFile)
      TanksFileWriter.writerow(Tank1csv)

TanksFile.close()

finally:
sock.close()
Units = "Litres"
Tank1 = "Tank 1 Volume"
print (Tank1,(Tank1Vol),(Units))`
```

Comment: I have been playing around with this and had anther idea. So... my python file gets all the information I need and logs it to a csv, I can use another file to run the code. Is it possible for me to use the import time function and run the original file with import myfile.py every 10 seconds. I have been playing around on a theme of this, but it only runs the code once.

Answer (score 0):

you can install modbus module using pip3 command. It has a client that will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

There are several python libraries for modbus : `pymodbus3`, `minimalmodbus`, `modbus-tk`. I recommend to pick one and use it for your project.

I am maintaining [modbus-tk](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/), so it would be my choice. :-)

You can have a look at this example to read registers : https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/examples/tcpmaster_example.py

I hope it helps